# SQL Combine Dates

Tags: sql

I am trying to combine dates as follows:

[image]

I used min(StartTime) and max(EndTime) but it doesn't work on the 2nd expected result. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Used the query below per recommendations. However,  it's still not working. I had to convert StartTime and EndTime as they have time values.

;with cte as (
select fb_id, convert(date,starttime) 'StartTime', convert(date,endtime) 'EndTime'
from invoicelife

```
union all
select t.fb_id, convert(date,cte.starttime) 'StartTime', convert(date,t.endtime) 'EndTime'
from cte join invoicelife t on cte.fb_id = t.fb_id and cte.endtime = t.StartTime and t.endtime = t.StartTime
```

), cte2 as (
select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by fb_id, endtime order by starttime)
from cte
)
select fb_id, convert(date,min(StartTime)) 'StartTime', convert(date,max(endtime)) 'EndTime'
from cte2
where rn=1
group by fb_id, StartTime
order by fb_id, StartTime;

Here's the original data

[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDW7U.png)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHlqE.png)

Comment: This is a standard "Gaps & Islands" problem. There are countless answer in SO for it, that depend on the specific database and its version. Please specify which database/version are you using.

Comment: i'm using SQL Serrver 2012 v11